# Error: Specify a machine to start using the terminal on vbox 7.0 Mac m1

Tags: boot, 20.04, virtualbox

I can install ubuntu just fine on vbox 7, but after I start it, it shows the purple screen(before ubuntu installation starts on the host machine) and then shows this error: You must specify a machine to start, using the command line.

Usage: VirtualBoxVM --startvm <name|UUID> Starts the VirtualBox virtual machine with the given name or unique identifier (UUID).

I tried reinstallation and rebooting the iso image but same error is occurring